# Why Laravel doens't reconize mcrypt even though I have everything installed correctly on Yosemite OSX?

Tags: php, macos, apache, laravel-4, osx-yosemite

I created a new project with Laravel, then I put it in the corresponding path for apache could execute, then I write the URL in a browser to open the project and I get the following message

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I installed  `mcrypt` with this command

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt
```

and work fine when I create a new project in laravel

I was searching and I found this [tutorial](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/) but still withouth work

1. Open `/etc/php.ini` and add the line below at the end `extension=mcrypt.so`.
   If there is no `php.ini` file,  then you need to make one from `php.ini.default` in the same location like so: `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`
2. allow write capability `sudo chmod u+w  /etc/php.ini`
3. Then add the line as above in your favourite text editor: `sudo nano /etc/php.ini`
4. add in the line: `extension=mcrypt.so`
5. Restart Apache `sudo apachectl restart`

but still without work, what can I do?

Comment: You're probably editing the wrong `php.ini`. Do a `phpinfo();` in the actual installation you will be using (either via Apache or the console) and note where the ini file is based. You're probably looking at the Apache installation.

Comment: @halfer ``Loaded Configuration File:/etc/php.ini`` and ``Scan this dir for additional .ini files:/Library/Server/Web/Config/php`` but I cant find the second path

Comment: Are you sure that's the PHP you've installed via Homebrew? You might just be looking at Apple's default Apache install here.

Comment: @halfer I think I installed PHP with XCode

Comment: Right, that would be my guess as to the problem. Stop the Apple default Apache, then install Apache and PHP from Homebrew. (That said, you should have received an error when you restarted, and you did not mention one, so I am assuming you did not receive one. That is odd in that case. What is the output of `locate mcrypt.so`?)

Comment: @halfer I need disable apache and php, then install via homebrew, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68527/discussion-between-zhelon-and-halfer).

Comment: Yes, that is my suggestion. Give it a go!

Comment: @halfer I install MAMP and I add

Comment: Please supply a full description of what you have now done. So, you didn't install Apache via Homebrew, and have switched to MAMP. OK. Are you still having the same problem? Did you edit the MAMP php.ini? If so, what is its path? Did you restart the right server? How did you do so?

Answer (score 0):

While it's always good to do PHP stuff on a local server, you will almost always run into the issue of getting everything set up correctly if you don't know what you're doing. My advice, use a service already provided for you.

Using Homestead (Laravel's Dev Environment) will help in getting projects setup very quickly. It'll also have all the PHP modules (e.g. mcrypt) already configured.

I'd take a look at Homestead: [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead)

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting: [Install mcrypt for php on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/)

**OR**

Just see your phpinfo(); it will give you the status for mcrypt.

**OR**

Try updating your php version. Visit: [Update PHP](http://php-osx.liip.ch/)

See, if that helps you.